# Is there a way to do size comparison?

Tags: prolog

I have recently discovered the language Prolog and have been doing exercises on its basics. I am currently creating a database on animal classes like `mammals`, `birds` and `reptiles`, I want to expand the database by having a size comparison within the animals but not sure how.

Here is my database.

```
warm_blooded(bat).
warm_blooded(penguin).

cold_blooded(crocodile).

has_fur(bat).

has_feathers(penguin).

has_scales(crocodile).

gives_birth_live(bat).

lays_eggs(penguin).
lays_eggs(crocodile).

produces_milk(bat).

has_lungs(crocodile).
has_lungs(bat).
has_lungs(penguin).


%% if the being belongs to the mammalai class ,mammalia being the scientific word for mammal
mammalia(X) :-  
    warm_blooded(X),
    produces_milk(X), 
    (
        has_fur(X)
    ;
        gives_birth_live(X)
    ),
    format('~w ~s mammal ~n', [X, "is a"]).

 %% if the being belongs to the aves class aves being the scientific word for bird
 aves(X) :- 
    warm_blooded(X), 
    has_feathers(X), 
    lays_eggs(X), 
    has_lungs(X),
    format('~w ~s bird ~n', [X, "is a"]).

 %% if the being belongs to the reptillia class(reptillia being the scientific word for reptile

 reptillia(X) :- 
    cold_blooded(X), 
    lays_eggs(X), 
    has_scales(X), 
    has_lungs(X),
    format('~w ~s reptile ~n', [X, "is a"]).
```

I've tried adding sizes within the parameters but I keep getting compilation errors. I want to have an output wherein the user is able to determine which animal is bigger when compared with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple an effective way is to just associate a size fact with each animal.

```
size(bat,1).
size(penguin,2).
size(crocodile,3).
```

Then add one predicate with two clauses to chose the larger of the two animals.

```
larger(A,B,A) :-
    size(A,S1),
    size(B,S2),
    S1 > S2.

larger(A,B,B) :-
    size(A,S1),
    size(B,S2),
    S2 >= S1.
```

Examples:

```
?- larger(penguin,crocodile,X).
X = crocodile.

?- larger(penguin,bat,X).
X = penguin ;
false.

?- larger(bat,bat,X).
X = bat.
```

Note that for examples where the the second animal is smaller, it tries the first clause and succeeds, but then has a choice point and so tries the second clause and fails. This is the pure solution.

If you want to use a cut to avoid the choice point, which is impure, you can do the following

```
larger_2(A,B,A) :-
    size(A,S1),
    size(B,S2),
    S1 > S2,
    !.

larger_2(A,B,B) :-
    size(A,S1),
    size(B,S2),
    S2 >= S1,
    !.
```

Examples:

```
?- larger_2(penguin,crocodile,X).
X = crocodile.

?- larger_2(penguin,bat,X).
X = penguin.

?- larger_2(bat,bat,X).
X = bat.
```

Another way as noted by Daniel Lyons is to use -[>/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2)

```
larger_3(A,B,Larger) :-
    size(A,SA),
    size(B,SB),
    (
        SA > SB
    ->
        Larger = A
    ;
        Larger = B
    ).
```

This variation is not one operator of just `->/2` but a combination of both [->/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=-%3E/2) and [;2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(%3B)/2).

This also does not leave a choice point and is impure because it too uses a cut (`!`). Using [listing/1](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=listing/1) we can see the implementation in Prolog.

```
?- listing('->'/2).
:- meta_predicate 0->0.

system:A->B :-
        call((   A
             ->  B
             )).

true.

?- listing(;/2).
:- meta_predicate 0;0.

system:A:B;A:C :- !,
        call(A:(B;C)).
system:A:B;C:D :-
        call(A:(B;C:D)).

true.
```

Notice the cut `!`.

How the two operators work together is noted in the SWI-Prolog [documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=(-%3E)/2).

```
The combination ;/2 and ->/2 acts as if defined as:

If -> Then; _Else :- If, !, Then.
If -> _Then; Else :- !, Else.
If -> Then :- If, !, Then.
```

One other point to note about the use of `->/2` with `;/2` is that the syntactic layout among many Prolog programmers is to use `()` with the combination and offset the operators `->/2` and `;2` so that the `;` stands out.

```
(
    % condition
->
    % true
;
    % false
)
```

When a `;` is used as an OR operator and not offset the `;` is often overlooked in doing a quick scan of the source code as it is seen as a comma `,` instead of a `;`.

Also note the absence of `.` or `,` after

```
SA > SB
```

and

```
Larger = A
```

and

```
Larger = B
```

but at the end an operator is needed,

```
).
```

Comment: You could avoid the cut with an explicit conditional too, something like `larger_3(A,B,Larger) :- size(A,SA), size(B,SB), SA > SB -> Larger = A ; Larger = B.` but I am probably screwing up the parenthesization.

Comment: @DanielLyons You are right I should add that. Just didn't want to explain why it was impure.